# How do I unlock the following characters?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

How do you unlock the following characters in order to complete the exploratory laboratory free play level : Magneto, Jean Grey, Storm, Iceman, Galactus and Cyclops.

Comment: All of those characters are unlocked at various points along the main story line. Some might also require spending studs to unlock the character after they become available for unlocking after a mission.

Answer (score 3):

All these characters are unlocked upon finishing the story mode.

Jean Grey, Iceman, Storm and Cyclops are unlocked in the chapter **Juggernauts and Crosses**. Magneto is unlocked in the chapter **Magnetic Personality** and Galactus is unlocked in the chapter **The Good, the Bad, and the Hungry**.